# where like нескольких условий php

Tags: php, mysql

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть код который ищет имя в таблице:

```
<?php
    $q=$_GET['q'];
    $my_data=mysql_real_escape_string($q);
    $mysqli=mysqli_connect('localhost','','','') or die("Database Error");
    $sql="SELECT name FROM users WHERE name LIKE '%$my_data%' ORDER BY name";
    mysqli_set_charset($mysqli, 'utf8');
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql) or die(mysqli_error());

    if($result)
    {
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
            echo $row['name']."\n";
        }
    }
?>
```

Как сделать поиск еще по lastname? Спасибо.

Comment: `WHERE name LIKE '%$my_data%' OR lastname LIKE '%$my_data%'` очевидно же ж...

Comment: @Akina а для echo? Поставил условие, но выводиться только имя.

Comment: Соответствующий IF(){}

Comment: @Akina подскажите пожалуйста с кодом.

Comment: @Akina пожалуйста, не могу разобраться как вывести name и lastname.